# Problemas com iReport Designer - No protocol specified

Tags: ireport

Olá! Boa tarde!

Meu problema é, basicamente, o seguinte:

Eu baixei o iReport Designer, mas não consigo executar. Quando dou um sudo ./ireport, o console retorna a seguinte mensagem:

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
No protocol specified

Comment: Pelo que o que li em alguns sites, o IReport não suporta o Java 8

Comment: Eita... Mas é possível rodar ele em uma versão anterior do java, e continuar usando o java 8 em outros projetos?

Comment: Sim, mas como fazer isso depende da distro utilizada

Comment: A versão é Ubuntu 17.10, sabe dizer como eu faço isso? Porque na Oracle eu não acho.

Comment: [Dá uma olhada aqui](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740757/switch-between-multiple-java-versions/740782)

Comment: Quando eu dou sudo apt-get update, aparece a seguinte mensagem: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.

Comment: Não vou conseguir ajudar, utilizo Antergos, sistema de pacotes diferente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que ele não tem suporte para o Java8.

Se você tem mais de uma instalação do JDK faça o seguinte:

- Como *root* rode o comando: `update-alternatives --config java`
- Copie o caminho da instalação do JDK que você tem, no meu caso o caminho é **/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle**
- abra o arquivo **ireport/etc/ireport.conf** e, na variável *jdkhome*, cole o caminho copiado
- saia do modo *root* e execute o **ireport** normalmente.

Se você não tem mais de uma instalação, terá de instalar outro JDK par funcionar. Ele não roda com Java8. Espero ter ajudado.